# Upload RecyclerView To Php Server Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am developing E-Store App I want to upload the cart data which i am getting from php server to recycler view. I want to upload the whole recycler view to the database using `Retrofit 2.0` and rest API.i want to know how to do it or there is another method to do it better

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to save to the database the list of objects that your RecyclerView id displaing. The list that you need is probably inside the adapter class.

Comment: yes @MarkWalczak

Answer (score 0):

You can use Room from Android Architecture Components (Jetpack) for storing data in local database.

Some Info: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

Comment: i want to store data in online server

Comment: sorry, your question was not clear. if you want to work only with server, then you should send POST request with needed parameters

Comment: for example, ```@FormUrlEncoded  @Post  fun sendData(@Field("parameter_key") parameterKey: String): Call<Response>```.  if you are using rxJava2 you can wrap with Observable/Single/Maybe/Completable or something else